# SQL Server: How to compare several overlapping date intervals and output parts of intervals based on condition

Tags: sql-server, date, intervals

I am attempting to compare multiple overlapping date intervals within a group, and output parts of each interval based on which of the overlapping intervals had the highest price during the overlap. Here's an example of the data:

[image]

From the above, I would like to output something like:

[image]

For ID=2, it is not too complicated, and I have a solution for this. But I have not been able to come up with a good solution for the example in ID=1, which can be visualized below (not to scale):

[image: Example overlap ID=1 solved]

Where red=200 (price), yellow=150 (price), and green=100 (price).

I tried utilizing the answer from [Cte to merge date intervals](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316064/aggregate-overlapping-date-intervals), but I am unable to reconfigure the proposed solution to output parts of the interval.

Here's the code for the example data:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TestTable;
CREATE TABLE #TestTable (
   ID Varchar(11),
   Place Varchar(50),
   Price Bigint,
   DateStart Date,
   DateEnd Date
);

INSERT INTO #TestTable (ID, Place, Price, DateStart, DateEnd)
VALUES (1, 'OnePlace', 100, '2023-01-01', '2023-05-01'), 
       (1, 'AnotherPlace', 150, '2023-02-01', '2023-06-01'), 
       (1, 'YetAnotherPlace', 200, '2023-03-01', '2023-04-01'), 
       (2, 'YetAnotherPlace', 200, '2023-01-01', '2023-04-01'),
       (2, 'OnePlace', 100, '2023-03-01', '2023-06-01');

SELECT * FROM #TestTable;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are working with `Date` datatype rather than anything more granular one way could be to simply expand out the date range to the constituent dates and see for each date what the place with the highest price was then collapse the groups back up into contiguous date ranges ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ImxvdcRr)).

Below uses `GENERATE_SERIES` for the expansion - on previous versions you could use an auxiliary numbers table.

```
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT ID, 
       Place, 
       Price, 
       Date = DATEADD(DAY, gs.value, DateStart),
       PriceRank = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,DATEADD(DAY, gs.value, DateStart) ORDER BY Price Desc, Place) ,
       gs.value
FROM #TestTable
CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(DAY, DateStart, DateEnd)) gs
), T2 AS
(
SELECT *,
       GrpFlg = CASE WHEN Price <> LAG(Price) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM T1
WHERE PriceRank = 1
), T3 AS
(
SELECT *,
       Grp = SUM(GrpFlg) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM T2

)
SELECT  ID, Place, Price, DateStart = MIN(Date), DateEnd = MAX(Date)
FROM T3
GROUP BY ID, Place, Price, Grp
ORDER BY ID, DateStart
```

For the numbers table version.

First create one...

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Numbers(Number INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT dbo.Numbers 
SELECT TOP 100000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) - 1
FROM sys.all_columns c1,sys.all_columns c2
```

... then change the definition of `T1` to

```
WITH T1 AS
(
SELECT ID, 
       Place, 
       Price, 
       Date = DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, DateStart),
       PriceRank = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,DATEADD(DAY, n.Number, DateStart) ORDER BY Price Desc, Place) ,
       n.Number
FROM TestTable 
INNER JOIN dbo.Numbers n ON n.Number BETWEEN 0 AND DATEDIFF(DAY, DateStart, DateEnd)
), /*Remainder of code is as above*/
```

Comment: This looks really interesting! GENERATE_SERIES is not included in SSMS 18, which is what I have to use. I have tried to use an auxiliary table (I have a date-table available with all dates going back to 01-01-1900), and use ROW_NUMBER to give each day in each Start- and End-intervals above a values and insert it as a "T0.5" table initially, but I struggle to get it to work. Would you be able to show me how to correctly insert an auxiliary numbers table in the above code?

Comment: @AndreasRedsted https://dbfiddle.uk/-A7IEdez

Comment: Works brilliantly, thanks a lot!